# Swift: Checking for the existence of a uitextfield

Tags: ios, swift, optional-values

I have a controller that will have a variable number of textfields. On a button press I want to check for the existence of, whether or not its empty, and check the character count of the input.

I'm trying the following, which works fine if homePhone exists

```
if homePhone?.text != ""{
if countElements(homePhone1.text) != 10{
    validInput = false
    validationError = "Home Phone must be 10 digits"
}
}
```

But when a textfield does not exist (mobile) I get a fatal error

```
if mobilePhone?.text != ""{
if countElements(mobilePhone.text) != 10{
    validInput = false
    validationError = "Mobile Phone must be 10 digits"
}
}

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Obviously I'm not doing the check correctly, optionals and unwrapping is continually tripping me up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unwrap your textfield and check if it exists:

```
if let mobilePhoneField = mobilePhone{
  if mobilePhoneField.text != ""{
    if countElements(mobilePhoneField.text) != 10{
        validInput = false
        validationError = "Mobile Phone must be 10 digits"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if let mobilePhoneField = mobilePhone - so this is part is unrapping?

Comment: Yes. That's the part.

Comment: thank you. For some reason I thought ! had something to do with unwrapping

Answer (score 0):

This will check if your optional variable is nil or not so you can safely unwrap it, actualy it will do it for you.

```
if let value = myOptionalVariable{
    //my optionalVariable is not nill i can do whatever i want
    value.text = "Yaay"
}
```